# Grails, Want to create a backlink from detail to master in the gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

The title tells almost all. If I entered a edit-form from the master-edit-form using the the detail-link in the master-form, I would like to have a link back to the masterform. Of course I could use the browsers back-button but it would be more conveniant to have a custom backlink.

I've tried the following twoo examples, found on this forum, but they didn't take me anywhere:

```
        <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.replace('${prevLoc}');">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.history.back();">Back</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a generic method of going back a page?

Try the following in your gsp

```
<g:link url="${request.getHeader('referer')}">Back</g:link>
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I needed. Thanks!